# MongoDB - finding common value between categories

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection of documents in the following format.  There are around 100K records:

```
{
    "category": 14412,
    "books": [
        "A",
        "B",
        "C",
        "E",
        "F",
    ]
},
{
    "category": 14413,
    "books": [
        "A",
        "B",
        "E"
    ]
},
{
    "category": 14414,
    "books": [
        "A",
        "E"
    ]
}
```

I would like the output like this which I can save into another collection. This would be an iterative process for each category (all the combination of category) in the collection. e.g. 14412,14413 and 14412, 14414, 14414, 14413...

```
{
    "category_source": 14412,
    "category_target": 14413,
    "common_books": [
        "A",
        "B",
        "E"
    ]
},
{
    "category_source": 14412,
    "category_target": 14414,
    "common_books": [
        "A",
        "E"
    ]
},
{
    "category_source": 14414,
    "category_target": 14413,
    "common_books": [
        "A",
        "E"
    ]
},
```

Would be grateful for any guidance.